# TypeScript Element implicitly has an 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some issues with TypeScript. I'm trying to transform some value that is coming from parent component to child. Parent is sending value that can be EN, FR or NL, and those values I should transform to numbers, so I did that:

```
const transform_translation = {
      'EN': 1,
      'FR': 2,
      'NL': 3
    };
```

But when I try to get value like `transform_translation[props.language]`, It says;

> S7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'any' can't be used to index type '{ EN: number; FR: number; NL:

Props:

```
props: {
    language: {
      type: String,
      default: ['EN', 'NL', 'FR'],
      required: true
    },
.
.
.
}
```

How should I define them then? I work first time with TS btw.

> number; }'.

Comment: Can you show the type definition for the props?

Comment: language: {
      type: String,
      default: ['EN', 'NL', 'FR'],
      required: true
    },

Comment: Are you sure that's the type on the props? Like, can you show me where you define the component? For a function component it would look something like `const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = (props) => {` or `const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => `, plus the corresponding definition of `MyComponentProps`

Answer (score 1):

You should tell ts what you're passing is not just string but limited to the available keys of the languages you have:

```
const transform_translation = {
  EN: 1,
  FR: 2,
  NL: 3
};

// create type out of valid keys of object
type Language = keyof typeof transform_translation;

const getLanguageNum = (lang: Language) => transform_translation[lang];

console.log(getLanguageNum("EN")); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either create an enum or type for the key like so. Then when accessing it you can cast the the key into the type as follows

```js
type ITransformTranslationKey = 'EN' | 'FR' | 'NL';
const transform_translation: Record<ITransformTranslationKey, number> = {
      'EN': 1,
      'FR': 2,
      'NL': 3
    };

const someVar: ITransformTranslationKey = 'E' + 'N'; // you can define the type here
transform_translation[someVar as ITransformTranslationKey] // or here
```

Comment: Result would be the same, because props.language is making a problem..

Comment: When do you get the issue exactly? When accessing the obj?